# Can Eclipse generate method-chaining setters

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, method-chaining

I'd like to generate method-chaining setters (setters that return the object being set), like so:

```
public MyObject setField (Object value) {
    this.field = value;
    return this;
}
```

This makes it easier to do one-liner instantiations, which I find easier to read:

```
myMethod (new MyObject ().setField (someValue).setOtherField (someOtherValue));
```

Can Eclipse's templates be modified to do this?  I've changed the content to include `return this;` but the signature is not changed.

Comment: I personally don't know the answer. However, you may find some results by searching for "fluent" interfaces. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: Just added potential plugin, as requested (not tested yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm eclipse (up to 3.5RC1) does not support "method chaining" setter generation.
It only allows for comment and body customization, not API modification of a setter (meaning a generated setter still return '`void`').

May be the plugin [**Builder Pattern**](http://boss.bekk.no/bpep/) can help here... (not tested though)

Classic way (not "goof" since it will always generate a "`void`" as return type for setter):
[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/images/generate_getter_setter_dialog.png))</sub>

Vs. new way ([Builder Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/news/design-pattern-builder-pattern), potentially used as an [Eclipse plugin](http://boss.bekk.no/bpep/))
[alt text http://www.javadesign.info/media/blogs/JDesign/DesignConcepts/DesignPatterns/GOF/Creational-BuilderPatternStructure.jpeg](http://www.javadesign.info/media/blogs/JDesign/DesignConcepts/DesignPatterns/GOF/Creational-BuilderPatternStructure.jpeg)

Comment: I was pretty sure that it wouldn't be core functionality.  Any idea about a plugin that does it?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use eclipse myself, but you'll have to change one of the standard templates if you can't find a feature.

It's called **method chaining** by the way (which might help with a Google search or two).

Comment: Thanks, I've amended the question to explicitly state that.